# Erro de Dependencia

Tags: c#, thread

Estou utilizando o `BackgroundWorker`

```
private BackgroundWorker BGWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
BGWorker.DoWork += BGWorker_DoWork;
BGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

private void BGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   ObterInformacoes();
}

private void BGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dgv.ItemsSource = ObterInformacoes();
}

private List<Informacoes> ObterInformacoes()
{
    List<Informacoes> func = gestores.gInfo.Recuperar(new Filtro[] { 
        new Filtro(eInfo.Ativa, true),
        new Filtro(eInfo.Recorrente, false)
    }).Select(f => new Informacoes(f)).ToList();

    return func.OrderBy(f => f.Nome).AsParallel().ToList();
}
```

E está me retornando este erro:

> Additional information: É necessário criar DependencySource no mesmo
>   Thread que DependencyObject.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vi a necessidade do uso do BackGroundWorker neste seu exemplo, tendo em vista que você chama o método `ObterInformacoes()` no método `_DoWork` do BW e depois chama-o novamente no `_RunWorkerCompleted`.

isto poderia ser melhorado da seguinte forma:

```
private BackgroundWorker BGWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
BGWorker.DoWork += BGWorker_DoWork;
BGWorker.ReportProgress = true; //Atenção para esta linha
BGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

private void BGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   e.Result = ObterInformacoes();
}

private void BGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var lista = e.Result as List<Informacoes>;
    dgv.ItemsSource = lista;
}

private List<Informacoes> ObterInformacoes()
{
    List<Informacoes> func = gestores.gInfo.Recuperar(new Filtro[] { 
        new Filtro(eInfo.Ativa, true),
        new Filtro(eInfo.Recorrente, false)
    }).Select(f => new Informacoes(f)).OrderBy(f => f.Nome).ToList();

    return func;
}
```

Acredito que isto deva funcionar.

Comment: O processamento da lista é feito na thread seprada, utilizando o `BackGroundWorker` e ao terminar o processamento ele notifica que terminou passando a lista como `Result` para o `BGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` que se responsabiliza pela exibição dos dados processados.

Comment: @RichardDias Posso estar errado, mas acredito que sua intenção no método `BGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` era escrever `dgv.ItemsSource = lista`, ao invés de chamar novamente o método `ObterInformacoes`. Além disso, ao invés de criar a `var lista` em `BGWorker_DoWork`, o correto não seria atribuir o resultado à propriedade `e.Result`?

Comment: Isso mesmo @ConradClark. Muito obrigado pelas observações. Já atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Você está usando o `AsParallel` ainda? Poste mais detalhes sobre o erro.

Comment: Mas fazendo isso, não faz sentido usar o `BackGroundWorker`

Comment: Adicione mais informações sobre: `gestores.gInfo`

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, na minha classe `Informacoes` tenho uma propriedade que é uma foto. Adicionei `Foto.Freeze()` e está funcionando o corretamente. Estou usando o `e.Result` como sugerido na resposta! Obrigado.